# Define ComboBox' DataTemplate for TextBox (and define search pattern) when IsEditable is True?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` whose `ItemsSource` is binding to a collection and the `SelectedItem` is binding to the properties of my `VieModel`. Let's call the binding properties `AvailableOptions` and `TargetOption` in `ViewModel`. And type of collection item and `TargetOption` is called `MyOption`. I have such requirements but I don't know how to fulfill them all:

1. It should be OK for the binding `TargetOption` to have NULL as value
2. I want to set a `DataTemplate` for the target type in `TargetOption` collection to be displayed in the `ComboBox`
3. If possible, I want use different `DataTemplate` for `MyOption` when then are in the drop-down of `ComboBox` and when one item is selected. Because my `UserControl` has limited space so it should be compact when item is selected and during the selection it should provide more information

As I said, I don't know how to do all of them. At first I have the XAML like this:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOption} ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableOptions}" >                          
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <MyNameSpace:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OptionDetailTemplate}" SelectedItemTemplate="{StaticResource OptionSimpleTemplate}" />
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ComboBox>
```

With a customized `ItemTemplateSelector`. I am able to do the requirement 2) and 3). My `OptionDetailTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OptionDetailTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" | " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and `OptionSimpleTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OptionSimpleTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" | " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" | " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

But now the problem is requirement 1). When the user select one option from the drop down list of the `ComboBox`, he can't put it as NULL back which should be allowed. This is because `AvailableOption` doesn't have a NULL object

I see that if I set `IsEditable` to True for the `ComboBox`, and set `TextSearch.TextPath` to `Code`, it allows the text quick search/assign and also allows to have a NULL value when the search text is totally deleted. But now when I ever select one, it only displays `Code` (the `OptionTemplate` does not have any effect any more because now it displays the selected item in a `TextBox`). This is not good since only `Code` is not enough for the user to tell what `Option` it is. But since I have multiple properties in `MyOption` class, how can I define the `DataTemplate` for the `TextBox` and also define the search routine?

Answer (score 0):

I have to be honest that I didn't fully understand your first requirement and its ramifications. however, I am really just answering to let you know that you don't even need to use a `DataTemplateSelector` to select between your two `DataTemplate`s. If you do *not* set the `x:Key` value on them, then they will be applied to the relevant items implicitly:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXamlNamespacePrefix:TargetOption}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" | " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXamlNamespacePrefix:MyOption}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" | " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
        <TextBlock Text=" | " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Furthermore, you could do all this data binding with just a single `TextBlock` if you use a `MultiDataTrigger`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}|{1}">
            <Binding Path="ShortName" />
            <Binding Path="Code" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Perhaps if you try clarifying your remaining problem (in your question), I might understand?

Comment: Yes. I realize the description is a bit obscure. `TargetOption` is not the name of the class, it is the name of the property, whose type is `MyOption`. And of course the items in collection `AvailableOptions` is also of type `MyOption`. The 2,3 requirements mean I want to display `MyOption` using different formats (when it is in the drop-down box I want to display more info and). My first part of XAML can satisfy 2 and 3 requirements.

Comment: But the problem is from the 1) requirement. It means I want to allow the binding to `TargetOption` to have NULL as value. In my first XAML code, in the beginning it is OK since no item is selected. But whenever the user selects one item from the drop-down list, he can't select to NULL back since the collection doesn't really contain the NULL object

Comment: That's why I added `IsEditable`, which adds an editable `TextBox` to the `ComboBox`. and when the text in the `TextBox` is deleted, the binding property `TargetOption` is then changed to NULL. But my question is I don't know how to customize the `DataTemplate` for this `TextBox` (the `ItemTemplate`doesn't apply to it) since I want to display/allow user to use search pattern other than only one property in the `TextBox`

Comment: Are you just asking how to add an empty item into your `ComboBox`?

Comment: Well, the main purpose to use `IsEnabled` is to allow empty item to be assigned to the `SelectedItem` binding property. But at the same time the user editable `TextBox` with auto-complete might also be useful. So if possible, I'd like to use `IsEnabled`. And I'd like to know how to customize the display format in this `TextBox`. By "customize", I mean both what it displays in the `TextBox` for the selected one and also what search pattern it uses